# Why are my followers trying to murder me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Esbern and Delphine keep attacking me, regardless of where I go or what I do, and I don't know how to get them to stop.

I didn't attack them and was just doing quests with them and do not know what triggered the attack on me. They keep killing me and it's really starting to get annoying. If anyone knows how to stop this please let me know, because I would really hate to start over.

Comment: did you try to sheathe your weapon?

Comment: Yes I've tried that many times

Comment: I have the Same thing but the wiki tells if it's a bug i need to restart over and i would realy hate that. i play On the PlayStation, any tips to fix It if It isnt that bug?

Comment: do you have high bounty?

Answer (score 15):

One possible explanation may be the fact that if you are a vampire in the final stages of the disease, everyone will begin to attack you on sight, even your companions, due to their fear of vampirism.

Comment: That's an interesting angle I didn't consider.

Answer (score 13):

There are some reports that Delphine's AI is buggy and will cause her to randomly turn hostile, but [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Delphine) says that she will be hostile if you have a bounty on your head, so it may not be all that random or buggy after all.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a high bounty for something. This happened to me when I had Farkas  as a follower. He was all glitched out so I went to Falkreath and let the guards read me the riot act, paid my bounty, and Farkas acted normal again.

Answer (score 1):

You are a vampire and need to drink some blood to reverse the stages.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me with my follower. I used Voice of the Imperial which made her stop attacking, but then she also left my service. Then I just had to ask her to follow me again and everything was fine. Yay.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well. Fast travel to another city, and then wait 48 hours (buy a room or use wait mode).
After that, she will be fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to make you like them again:

You have to beat them until they are down on one knee and then heal them with the "helping hands" spell. This will snap them back to reality.

Answer (score 0):

Serena tried pulling this shit on me too.  If you have a follower attacking you it can be something as mundane as them stupidly getting hit by those boulders bandits try to drop and you get blamed for the damage (stupid bug).  However, for some reason when you fast travel (I used a carriage) it resets their aggression and they will go from Hyde back to Jeckyl.